# Recursive SQL function returning array has extra elements when self-invocation uses array function

Tags: arrays, postgresql, recursion

**Goal**: write a function in PostgreSQL SQL that takes as input an integer array whose each element is either `0`, `1`, or `-1` and returns an array of the same length, where each element of the output array is the sum of all adjacent nonzero values in the input array having the same or lower index.

Example, this input:

```
{0,1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,0}
```

should produce this result:

```
{0,1,2,3,4,0,-1,-2,0}
```

Here is my attempt at such a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION runs(input int[], output int[] DEFAULT '{}')
RETURNS int[] AS $$
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN cardinality(input) = 0 THEN output
    ELSE runs(input[2:],
              array_append(output, CASE
                WHEN input[1] = 0 THEN 0
                ELSE output[cardinality(output)] + input[1]
              END)
             )
    END
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Which gives unexpected (to me) output:

```
# select runs('{0,1,1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0}');
                  runs                  
----------------------------------------
 {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,0,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,0}
(1 row)
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 14.4.  While I am ignorant of why there are more elements in the output array than the input, the `cardinality()` in the recursive call seems to be causing it, as also does using `array_length()` or `array_upper()` in the same place.

**Question**: how can I write a function that gives me the output I want (and why is the function I wrote failing to do that)?

**Bonus extra**: For context, this input array is coming from `array_agg()` invoked on a table column and the output will go back into a table using `unnest()`.  I'm converting to/from an array since I see no way to do it directly on the table, in particular because `WITH RECURSIVE` forbids references to the recursive table in either an outer join or subquery.  But if there's a way around using arrays (especially with a lack of tail-recursion optimization) that will answer the general question (But I am still very very curious why I'm seeing the extra elements in the output array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything indicates that you have found a reportable Postgres bug. The function should work properly, and a slight modification unexpectedly changes its behavior. Add `SELECT;` right after `$$` to get the function to run as expected, see [Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7f1a0a89c614235864f534f35fa47cf1).

A good alternative to a recursive solution is a simple iterative function. Handling arrays in PL/pgSQL is typically simpler and faster than recursion.

```sql
create or replace function loop_function(input int[])
returns int[] language plpgsql as $$
declare
    val int;
    tot int = 0;
    res int[];
begin
    foreach val in array input loop
        if val = 0 then tot = 0;
        else tot := tot + val;
        end if;
        res := res || tot;
    end loop;
    return res;
end $$;
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=38605b30885b42103bec5bcf9977f73a)

---

The OP wrote:

> this input array is coming from `array_agg()` invoked on a table column and the output will go back into a table using `unnest()`.

You can calculate these cumulative sums directly in the table with the help of window functions.

```sql
select id, val, sum(val) over w
from (
    select 
        id, 
        val, 
        case val 
            when 0 then 0 
            else sum((val = 0)::int) over w 
            end as series
    from my_table
    window w as (order by id)
    ) t
window w as (partition by series order by id)
order by id
```

Test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7253a49b054055faa4c0e5b9bd372bc9)

Comment: Bug confirmed by Tom Lane: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/291122.1659915101%40sss.pgh.pa.us